# Linux Server (php mail) sends attatchments Windows IIS (php mail) does not (otherwise mail work perfect)

Tags: php, iis-7, smtp, attachment

I have a script (employment application form) that sends an html email with file attachments. It was tested and developed on a linux server but is being deployed on windows iis7. The problem, is that the file attachments being sent through php mail (smtp) are apparently being stripped of all their data. The files arrive with the ext and file name, but the files size is now 304 bytes or 260 bytes. What could be causing this and how can I resolve.

Comment: Could be a network issue, could be a mail issue with windows server, could be permissions issue with accepting the attachment (depends on how attachment is getting attached to email in your code), etc.  MOre or less it depends so can you provide some more details.  It could even be who you are mailing... for example we had an email problem and it turned it was not a code/system problem but the manager of the listserv was not allowing our system's address to mail that particular listserv.  Funny how much debugging and code review you can do until you realize what a second its not our issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that C:\windows\temp did not have IIS_IUSRS with read and write access.

So if you run into this problem:

1. navigate to C:\windows\temp *****
2. Right click and it will pull up the properties.
3. Navigate to the security tab and under (group or user name:) click on edit.
4. on the next screen if IIS_IUSRS is not listed click add
5. on the next screen you will see a text field, enter IIS_IUSRS
6. now you should be able to set permissions.
7. now just click on iis_usrs under the security tab and click on read & execute, read, and write and set to allow.

***** this is set in php.ini, this is the default setting for temporary files under windows, your php.ini file might be something different, so double check to be sure.
You should now be good to go.  I hope that my answer can help someone else down the road.

Answer (score 1):

PHP actually doesn't send mail itself.  The call to `mail` is just a pass through to the system mailer.  You tested on a linux machine using sendmail or something similar but windows mailers are different.  Test on the exact environment and you will be able to debug.